# Xcode 6.1 using same 2x image for iPhone 6 and 4s simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, image

I'm using Asset Catalog for images. My app contains full screen tutorial pages. Under images.xcassets for a single image asset for iPhone there are 4 versions. 1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x and 3x.

I'm using Xcode 6.1. When the app is run on 4s simulator it uses 2x version of the image. Same image is being used for iPhone 6 simulator. No matter if I set Deployment Target to 7.1, 8.0 or 8.1 same thing happens.

I've attached a test project explaining the issue. If you run the project in simulator, both iPhone 4s and iPhone 6 showing the 2x version image.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gon4czetkya485/AssetCatalogTest.zip?dl=0

How can I easily show different image for 4s and 6 using Asset Catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way around this.  I tried duplicating the rules from a launch image and the asset catalog drops images with the 667h and 736h subtypes used by launch images.

You'd think this would work but it doesn't:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "4.png"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "6.png",
      "subtype" : "667h",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your best approach is the old-fashioned way.  Create images for each size with names like test-667 and do something like:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test-%g", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only work around for now. Apple seems to be not interested to support iPhone 4/4s any longer after launch of iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, we should be more careful with the documentation.

The `subtype` parameter is only available for **Launch Image Type**, and not for any other **Image Set Type**.

Please see these two links for prove:

[Image Set Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html)

[Launch Image Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/LaunchImageType.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to the iPhone 4s / 5 / 5S and 6 using 2x times. Where as the 6 Plus will use the 3x version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with fullscreen images. But I haven't found anything suitable, so I wrote a category that fixes this problem. You can find it [at github](https://github.com/accidbright/ABImageLoader). It uses old-fashioned method of creating multiple images in that app bundle, but it allows to set different images for different idioms, orientations and screens.