# name for resized iphone 6 image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, iphone-6

So ive always been able to get away with using the same image name in a line of code such as backgroundimage.png when applying a background image to a toolbar and when its deployed on an iphone 5 it automatically uses the backgroundimage@2x.png.   Now that iphone 6 needs a resized @2x.png image as well how do i differentiate this in my code?  what i mean is that now i cant just use the same image name for my resized 6 background image in my code as my original image.png because both the 5 and 6 would have the same name.

Am i supposed to write an if statement checking if the app is being ran on a 6 and then deploy my code with the specific iphone 6 image name @2x.png?

Comment: Did you look at some of the questions listed to the right under the "Related" section? It seems a few cover this already.

Comment: Yes I did but all the ones I came across that asked something similar were unanswered. If you have found one that explains this, could you point me in that direction?

Comment: I looked into this a while back and found the asset types used by launch images don't translate to normal images (at least with asset catalogs, didn't try non-catalog images). http://stackoverflow.com/a/26615830/860000. For whatever reason Apple decided not to allow suffixes for those screen sizes.